# Images are cropped or not displayed at all in mail Outlook

Tags: email, outlook

When testing mail in Outlook the images are cropped or not displayed:

[image: Screenshot mail with cropped images]

Image size: 80x80px.

Image weight: 1,7kB.

Part of mail markup with image:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-family: 'Arial'; vertical-align: top; padding: 0;" valign="top">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="left"
                  style="font-family: 'Arial'; font-size: 0px; padding: 0; word-break: break-word;">
                  <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"
                    border="0"
                    style="color:#333333;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;line-height:23px;table-layout:auto;width:100%;border:none;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid #ECECEC; width:100%">
                        <td
                          style="font-family: 'Arial'; padding: 36px 0 27px 0; vertical-align: middle; text-align: left; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: 125px"
                          width="125" valign="middle" align="left">
                            <img src="https://test.natalia.tot/165-cart_default/product-name.jpg" alt="Product name" style="line-height: 100%; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: 0; display: block; outline: none; text-decoration: none; height: auto; width: 100%; font-size: 13px;" height="auto" width="100%" border="0">
                          </td>
                        <td
                          style="font-family: 'Arial'; padding: 36px 5px 27px 0; vertical-align: middle;"
                          valign="middle">
                          <h3
                            style="font-family: 'Arial'; margin: 0; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 600; color: #1D1D1D; font-size:14px;">
                            Product name</h3>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Normal image display is expected.
Does anyone know why images are cropped sometimes in Outlook or not displayed at all ?